# How can I select a Telerik grid (radgrid) for asp.net ajax row on rightclick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a telerik grid. (asp.net ajax)

Some of my columns are formatted as hyper links () and those links call a telerik menu.

So When a user clicks (NOT right click) on a cell of such column, the context menu shows up - that's fine.

But the problem is the row that user just right clicked DOES NOT get selected.

I have set all allowSelect properties. Rows get selected when a menu isn't involved.

Because of this I cant get the selected row from javascript.

```
var grid = $find(dynamicControlId);
var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
var selectedRows = MasterTable.get_selectedItems();
```

selectedRows.length is always 0. When I run the above code when a user clicks on a context menu item.

link that calls the context menu to show

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"commandManager(event, businessParams);\">
```

It looks like the cell click event stops firing after showing the menu.

my aspx

```
 <telerik:RadContextMenu ID="RadContextMenu1" Runat="server" 
    OnClientItemClicked="contextMenuItemClicked" Skin="Black">
 </telerik:RadContextMenu>


    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
        Skin="Default" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        onitemdatabound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
        <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
          <Scrolling AllowScroll="true"  UseStaticHeaders="true" ScrollHeight="10px"/>
          <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
          <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated"></ClientEvents>
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView AllowPaging="true">
            <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" />
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

How can I make the grid select the row when a user clicks on a hyper-linked cell? What am I missing?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-detect-left-or-right-click-selecting-a-row.aspx